# Google Play rejects APK based on package name

Tags: android, google-play, package, publish, package-name

Been building an app within MIT's App Inventor (herecy on this site I know.) I uploaded the first version to Google Play yesterday and all went smoothly. Tried to push a new APK to production this morning but got this error;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzBD9.png

(sorry not enough rep to post images)

Confused, I went ahead and decompiled the APK and got this;

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker.IGSoundboard"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="IGSoundboard" android:icon="@drawable/ya" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".Screen1" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker.IGSoundboard.Board" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.ListPickerActivity" android:screenOrientation="behind" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.WebViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="behind" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see, `package="appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker.IGSoundboard"`
which matches the one Google Play is requesting. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Capitalization in SoundBoard is different on the word Board

instead of

```
appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker.IGSoundboard
```

it should be

```
appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker.IGSoundBoard
```

IGSoundBoard with a capital 'B'

Comment: your welcome, things like that happen to me all the time when im up for long hours programming :)

Comment: What if the package was `package="appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker"`? Would the applicationId in gradle (Android Studio) be only "appinventor.ai_benjamdavidstocker"?